# Handling flyout menu visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, overflow

I built a sidebar component but having problems with overflow. I want to show a menu from the sidebar

Here is a draft I have now:
`sidebar = drawer -> list -> list-item -> list-item shows title and absolute positioned menu`

The drawer component should be visible, but then it can't be scrollable.

If I put `overflow-y:scroll` on list, then x axis is also scrollable.

I see that this is a common problem.

Any suggestion

Comment: share a snippet please

Comment: @SimoneRossaini here is a rough example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-worker-pkes7

Comment: So you need overflow y and not x right?

Comment: I want to be able to show that absolute positioned menu, but also to be able to scroll inside the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `overflow-x: hidden` or can give fixed width as well.

but i will be able to provide right solution if you can share your html and css.

Comment: here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-worker-pkes7
try make it scrollable

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cori-gj3vr?file=/src/styles.css

i hope your problem is solved.. if not.. please feel free to ask again.

Comment: It should be outside the sidebar

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am sorry then we cant use position fixed for it. https://codepen.io/Harpreet-Singh-Dhot/pen/YzGaPRx here i have made something for you..

Happy New Year.

Comment: It has to be fixed, and then it doesn't work.